# Explain Multidegree of a polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, terminology

**Definition** (The book Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms, Cox et al, pages 59-60 on 2008 edition):

> Let $f=\sum_a a_a x^a$ be a nonzero polynomial in $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ and let > be a monomial order.
>
> The **multidegree** of f is $\quad\quad$ $multideg(f)=max(\alpha\in\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0} : a_a\ne 0)$.
>
> Example: $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$$multideg(f)=(3,0,0)$ for $f=4xy^2z+4z^2-5x^3+7x^2z^2.$

Please explain the definition: maximising each value in the n-tuple $\alpha$ but with respect to what is the multidegree calculated like in the case of $multidegree(f)$ above? With respect to exponents, monomial count, with respect to variable distribution -- thank you for any clarification!

Comment: What ordering is the maximum taken with respect to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of **multidegree** depends on a *monomial ordering* chosen. This is a total order on the set of all monomials that has the following aditional property:

- For all monomials $m,n$ and $p$, $m < n$ implies $p\cdot m < p\cdot n$

In this case, we say that $<$ is an *admissible order*. A tipical example of a monomial ordering is the *lexicographic order*, defined as follows: for $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0}$, $\alpha < \beta$ if and only if the leftmost nonzero entry of $\beta - \alpha$ is positive.

Considering this ordering, $(3,0,0)$ is indeed the multidegree of $$f=4xy^2z+4z^2-5x^3+7x^2z^2,$$ but this may not be the case when you consider other orderings.

Comment: How did you calculate the $(3,0,0)$? 3 for the sum of exponents in $4xy^2z$. What  are the zeros for?

Comment: It's the "vector" representation of the monomial $x^3y^0z^0$.

Comment: And this uses monomial ordering in the example: (i) > is a total (or linear ordereing on $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n$ (ii) your bullet point (iii) > is a well-ordering on $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n$ i.e. every nonempty subset of $\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0}$ has a smallest element under >. Thank you for the  comment +1, understood :)

Comment: @hhh I'm glad it helped ;)